# How to display the keys which contain the same value?

Tags: php

I'm currently stuck on figuring out how to display the keys which contain the same value.

I have an array with keys and values, I use a statement
`if(array_count_values($arr) > 1)` to print only if there is a duplicate value in the array. However I don't know how to print the duplicate value keys.

```
 if(array_count_values($arr) > 1) {
  echo "The following files are the same: \n";
 }
```

Inside the $arr are keys and values. Keys are file names and values are their inodes.

Here is an example array

`[test1.php] => 130313
 [test2.php] => 130333
 [test3.php] => 130313
 [test4.php] => 140393`

How can I print `The following files are the same: test1.php, test2.php`?

Comment: Did you mean test1 and test3 are the same?

Comment: Yes they are the same

Comment: I'm not sure if there are direct array functions to do what you want. You just need to work out a simple logic to do that.

Comment: @RemigiuszBiernat I've added an answer that partitions the files in a simple functional way, using mainly build in array functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$histogram = array();
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if (array_key_exists($v, $histogram)) {
        $histogram[$v][] = $k;
    } else {
        $histogram[$v] = array($k);
    }
}

foreach ($histogram as $keys) {
    echo 'The following files are the same: ' . implode(', ', $keys) . "<br />\r\n";
}
```

It should work, I just coded it without testing. Did I solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've added another file to make it more interesting:

```
$input = [
    "test1.php" => 130313,
    "test2.php" => 130333,
    "test3.php" => 130313,
    "test4.php" => 140393,
    "test5.php" => 130333,
];
```

This simple solution first prepares a map from inodes to files then "walks" through the input array to partition the files according to inode:

```
$inode_map = array_fill_keys(array_values($input), []);
array_walk($input, function ($inode, $file) use (&$inode_map) {
    $inode_map[$inode][] = $file;
});
```

`$inode_map` now contains:

```
Array
(
    [130313] => Array
        (
            [0] => test1.php
            [1] => test3.php
        )

    [130333] => Array
        (
            [0] => test2.php
            [1] => test5.php
        )

    [140393] => Array
        (
            [0] => test4.php
        )
)
```

If you want to locate duplicates files/inodes you can filter the map:

```
$duplicates_only = array_filter($inode_map, function ($files) { 
    return count($files) > 1;
});

foreach ($duplicates_only as $inode => $files) {
    echo "The following files are the same ($inode): " . join(", ", $files) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: You could replace the `array_walk` with `foreach` if you prefer that syntax

Answer (score -1):

Try this!

```
foreach ($arr as $file1=>$value1){
    foreach ($arr as $file2=>$value2){
        if($file1!=$file2  && $value1==$value2){
            echo "<p>The following files are the same: $file1 =>$value1, $file2=>$value2 </p>";
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: In case there are three files that are the same, this solution will show three lines with two files in each. Confusing